# Watch for SD Card Insertion

Tags: swift, macos

I would like my app to be notified when the user inserts an SD card. I tried adding an observer, but no notifications are received.

```
class SDCardWatcher: NSObject {
    public override init() {
        super.init()
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.onDiskMounted(_:)), name: .NSWorkspaceDidMount, object: nil)
    }

    @objc public func onDiskMounted(_ notification : Notification) {
        // This code is never executed
        print(notification.description)
    }
}
```

I am new to MacOS so would appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: How are you creating and storing your `SDCardWatcher` object, are you sure it's not being released?

Comment: @EmilioPelaez I have a member variable in the `AppDelegate` class `var sdWatcher: SDCardWatcher = SDCardWatcher()`, so I think it should be valid for the life of the app.